# Difference between construct url directly and parameters in iOS post networking

Tags: ios, networking, afnetworking

There are 2 methods in 'post' networking method in iOS ,

> 1.construct url directly like
>
> let url = URL(string: "http://host?parameter1=p1&parameter2=p2")

use this url 'post' to server

> 2.let dictionary = ["parameter1":"p1","parameter2":"p2"]

use this dictionary as a parameter 'post' to server

What is the difference between them?Or, they are the same.

Comment: Usually, in a GET Method, you put the parameters in the URL with ?key1=value1&key2=value2 etc. While in POST, you put the parameters in the Body (`httpBody` property of `NSURLRequest`). AFNetworking put the parameters itself in the Body in theory in POST, and in GET it put them into the URL.

Comment: @Larme is correct, that is the main difference between GET and POST methods. There is one drawback in GET method that, if you are using the GET method, you are limited to a maximum of 2,048 characters, minus the number of characters in the actual path.

Comment: Actually in first method you passed data via url parameters not using httpBody.As @iPeter says you can send limited characters only.you can do it(GET) without using POST.But the last method doing actual posting either small or big data.

Comment: @Larme But In post method using 1.url without parameter. It feels nothing different between them. The only difference is iPeter says?Will be side effects using 1.(url directly) in post method

Comment: @DS Dharma Will be side effects using 1.(url directly) in post method

Comment: @iPeter Only this difference? Or if don't using parameter in post, will it be caused big issues

Comment: @Larme It's not related to POST method..you can pass url parameters in GET & other type also...it's calling header param.HttpBody is a actual way to post.

Comment: @DSDharma It's "usually" the case. I've encountered POST method where there were some params in URL, and the other in body. It's just "most use case", and AFNetworking check the method if I remember correctly to know where to put the params (at least by default).